# What is the best way to crimp high temperature wire with uninsulated quick disconnect terminals?

Tags: electrical, wiring, crimp

I need to make a jumper wire to connect an electric range surface element to its temperature limiter.
[image]

What I have available is posted in these pictures:

high temp Teflon fiber glass insulated wire
[image]

high temp quick disconnect female terminals
[image]

wire stripper/crimping tool
[image]

I'm struggling to understand how to crimp the wire into these terminals. Are you supposed to crimp only uninsulated wire, or should some of the insulation be crimped too for a more secure connection?
If it is the latter, wouldn't the insulated part part cause interference on the connection of the uninsulated wire part?
Is there a good video or schematic how to make the crimp with my available tool, or does it require a special crimping tool?
I am worried that if I mess the crimp, given that the current expected in a dual coil surface element can be pretty high (15Amp max), the wire might burn again.
The available space is also pretty tight and the jumper wire needs to be bent to connect to the 2 spade terminals (which will put strain at the crimp of the female terminal).

Answer (score 3):

You *should* crimp both, but it doesn't look like you have the right connectors.

If the gauge difference between wire & overall shielded cable isn't too much, you can do this with a single crimp, but if you look at the existing spade connectors on your cooker, you'll see they have 2-part clamps. The wider part holds the shield, the narrower just the bare wire.

[image]

This needs a more specialist connector and crimping tool, or if you're very careful, two bites of the cherry at different compressions.

As these things are likely to only be touched once or twice in their lives and are not particularly subject to vibration, you could get away with just crimping the bare wire, but to do it 'properly', it should be both.

Comment: Better answer than mine.